# jquery cannot get elements id with 'this'

Tags: jquery, this

I'm kind of confused about 'this' in functions.

Why i dont get 'spanID' as id of the element on which i clicked?

HTML

```
<span id="spanID" onclick="alertIt()">something</span>
```

JS

```
function alertIt(){
    alert($(this).attr("id"))
}
```

here is [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lqqnx/)

Comment: Because $(this) within your function refers to the window object, which has no ID.

Answer (score 1):

I don't include the function call inside the span tag,

I just do:

```
<span id="spanID">something</span>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#spanID").click(function(){
        alert($(this).attr("id"));
    });
});
```

Comment: That's what i would do aswell.

Answer (score 1):

add `this` to alertIt() function

```
<span id="spanID" onclick="alertIt(this)">something</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
 <span id="spanID" onclick="alertIt($(this))">something</span>
```

Javascript

```
function alertIt(obj){
 alert($(obj).attr("id"))
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/akhildave/Lqqnx/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Use following

```
$("span").on("click",function(){
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
})
```

working fiddle [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lqqnx/)

Answer (score 0):

You are facing an issue because `$(this)` within your function refers to the window object. You should pass `this` inside `onclick="alertIt(this)"` like:

```
<span id="spanID" onclick="alertIt(this)">something</span>
function alertIt(a){
    console.log(a.id);
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kunknown/Lqqnx/2/)**

or

You should use jquery [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) event like:

```
<span id="spanID">something</span>
$("span").click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/kunknown/Lqqnx/4/)

Answer (score 0):

The `this` selector just get's the element it's nested in. Example:

```
$("#example").click(function(){
   $(this).fadeOut(500);
});
```

In your code, there was no element nesting the `this` selector .

Answer (score 0):

Because when you create an inline event handler, you are creating an anonymous function:

```
onclick="alertIt()"
```

is like:

```
function() {
    alertIt();
}
```

An event handler bound using jQuery has the same behavior:

```
$('#spanID').click(function() {
    alertIt();
});
```

The anonymous function has the correct context, but the context won't be passed to other functions unless you do so explicitly:

```
onclick="alertIt(this)"
```

or

```
$('#spanID').click(function() {
    alertIt(this);
});
```

and

```
function alertIt(obj) {
    alert(obj);
}
```

---

```
onclick="alertIt.call(this)"
```

or

```
$('#spanID').click(function() {
    alertIt.call(this);
});
```

and

```
function alertIt() {
    alert(this);
}
```